# how to calculate co-occurence with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a verge large transaction data ，
looks like:

| transactionid | items |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | i1 |
| 1 | i2 |
| 2 | i3 |
| 2 | i1 |

how to calculate co-occurence matrix with data.table or python
ps: the ordinary methods doesn't work since the big data
the expected output is

|  | i1 | i2 | i3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| i1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| i2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| i3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't `data.table` but it should work for you:

```
df <- crossprod(table(df)) 
diag(df) <- 0
df <- as.data.frame(df)
```

Gives us:

```
   i1 i2 i3
i1  0  1  1
i2  1  0  0
i3  1  0  0
```

Comment: thank u !  it did work in a small size data, but the  transaction data has more than one hundred million rows

Comment: @Philo For larger data you may check the dedicated tool `arules::apriori`. See timings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63323851/count-common-sets-of-items-between-different-customers)

Comment: @Henrik it also doesn't work with lager data ...